# Remove duplicates based on set of conditions in two columns (time data)

Tags: r, datetime, duplicates

Below is a sample of a dataset with the attendance time sheet. I want to retain the record for the earliest punch_in and the last punch_out (i.e id-1, name-sam, punch_in -8/6/2015 8:00:00 and punch_out- 8/6/2015 16:05:00). How do I remove the other duplicate entries in R?

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4)
name<-c("sam","sam","sam","sam","jack","john","jude")
sex<-c("M","M","M","M","M","M","F")
punch_in<-c("8/6/2015 8:00:00","8/6/2015 8:05:00","8/6/2015 8:00:00","8/6/2015 8:05:00","8/6/2015 8:06:00","8/6/2015 7:59:00","8/6/2015 8:00:00")
punch_out<-c("8/6/2015 16:00:00","8/6/2015 16:00:00","8/6/2015 16:05:00","8/6/2015 16:05:00","8/6/2015 16:00:00","8/6/2015 16:05:00","8/6/2015 16:05:00")
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,name,sex,punch_in,punch_out))
```

Comment: p.s. you can just do `data.frame(id,name,sex,punch_in,punch_out)` instead of `as.data.frame(cbind(id,name,sex,punch_in,punch_out))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4)
name<-c("sam","sam","sam","sam","jack","john","jude")
sex<-c("M","M","M","M","M","M","F")
punch_in<-c("8/6/2015 8:00:00","8/6/2015 8:05:00","8/6/2015 8:00:00","8/6/2015 8:05:00","8/6/2015 8:06:00","8/6/2015 7:59:00","8/6/2015 8:00:00")
punch_out<-c("8/6/2015 16:00:00","8/6/2015 16:00:00","8/6/2015 16:05:00","8/6/2015 16:05:00","8/6/2015 16:00:00","8/6/2015 16:05:00","8/6/2015 16:05:00")
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(id,name,sex,punch_in,punch_out))

library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(id, name, sex) %>%                 # for each combination of id, name, sex
  summarise(punch_in = first(punch_in),       # keep the first punch in
            punch_out = last(punch_out)) %>%  # keep the last punch out
  ungroup()                                   # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 4 x 5
#   id    name  sex   punch_in         punch_out        
#   <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>            <fct>            
# 1 1     sam   M     8/6/2015 8:00:00 8/6/2015 16:05:00
# 2 2     jack  M     8/6/2015 8:06:00 8/6/2015 16:00:00
# 3 3     john  M     8/6/2015 7:59:00 8/6/2015 16:05:00
# 4 4     jude  F     8/6/2015 8:00:00 8/6/2015 16:05:00
```

This assumes that rows are order by date, so for each id the first one is the earliest one and the last one is the most recent one.

Comment: That works if i group the three variables id,name and sex together but i would like to retain other variables in the dataset but not group them. The original dataset has other variables also that need to be retained.

Comment: It depends on how many unique values the other variables have. You have to update your example and include the other variables as well.